# Reading from Skydrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

I want to do this, I want to access to my Skydrive with a Winform application, if it's possible. Actually I want to access some of my anywhere, or access some other people access to them as well, but prefer not on a browser or Windows phone. Access mostly will be just a Read access.

1. Do you have a better solution for this situation??
2. What should or could I do??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SkyDrive has an [official RESTFul API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx). So go ahead to this site and start reading the documentation in order to understand how this API works.

There's also a non-official [.NET client](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/).

Comment: First thank you for the reply,
Second, I read the first link, but the problem is, it's mostly about the Windows 8 or Windows phone, or Javascript. So none of them are useful to me.
About the second link, I read and downloaded something from there, but no use. Either not working, nor not working again!! :D
But thanks anyway.